# how to custom devexpress gridview popup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gridview, popup, devexpress-mvc

My question may be a little bit weird because it makes me confused.
Among all the documentations that I find on the devexpress site, none of them have examples based on ASP.NET MVC, but  just for ASP.NET Core or Winforms or the use of Devextreme and not devExpress.

I have create with devexpress a gridview with Edit button that open popup.
I want to customize the popup but don't know how and don't find an exemple.

If someone can give me the way or exemple.

Thanks you...

Comment: What things you're tried already? Do you mean using `PopupEditForm` on GridView like in this example: https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxGridViewDemos/Editing/EditModes?

Comment: Yes, i have used GridViewEditingMode.PopupEditForm  on GridView like on the link

Comment: And what kind of customizations you want to achieve with current setup? Provide in details what you're trying & which expected results by modifying `PopupEditForm` after clicking GridView's edit button.

Comment: What i want to modify is :
* change the button name, 
* add new button, 
* modify the Items field name and the input size and type, 
* add picture on the popup.

The add and new popup that i want have been design by the user and contain company logo, and the fields name have been change to make user confortable (we can't change it in the database) ...

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the `SettingsPopup` property to the `GridViewSettings`settings and then edit the `GridViewEditFormPopupSettings` member, check the [class reference](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.GridViewEditFormPopupSettings.members) for the different settings you can customize. Here's a small example :

```
settings.SettingsEditing.Mode = GridViewEditingMode.PopupEditForm;
settings.SettingsPopup.EditForm.VerticalAlign = PopupVerticalAlign.Below;
settings.SettingsPopup.EditForm.HorizontalAlign = PopupHorizontalAlign.Center;
settings.SettingsPopup.EditForm.Width = 500;
settings.SettingsText.PopupEditFormCaption = settings.Name.ToUpper();
```